# IHostedService is not working perfectly some lines of code not firing how to handle it?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using IHostedService to manage bulk of log inserting. It will run as a background service. But It is not keep going on after for loop  in AsyncConsumer method. How can I use IHostedSErvice as a Background worker permonently always cheking any logs in logs list and consume it.Thank for your help.(Please look at below picture)

```
     public class QuickLog
    {
        private static BlockingCollection<SimpleLog> data = new BlockingCollection<SimpleLog>();
        public static async Task Producer(SimpleLog pageviewLog)
        {

            await Task.Run(() => data.TryAdd(pageviewLog, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
        }

        public static async Task AsyncConsumer()
        {
            var _client = ElasticConfig.GetClient();
            var logs = new List<SimpleLog>();
             foreach (var item in data.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                logs.Add(item);
(After FOR LOOP BELOW CODE NEVER RUN!!!!)
            var response = await _client.IndexManyAsync(logs, logs.FirstOrDefault().IndexName, logs.FirstOrDefault().IndexType);
            if (!response.IsValid)
                throw response.OriginalException;

        }
    }
```

BackgroundService.cs:

```
  public class LogBackgroundService : IHostedService
    {
        public  async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await  QuickLog.AsyncConsumer();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), cancellationToken);
            }

        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
 services.AddHostedService<LogBackgroundService>();
```

Program.cs:

```
   public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();

            var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder().ConfigureServices(services =>services.AddHostedService<LogBackgroundService>());


        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The StartAsync method should only **start** the service. You are doing all of the work inside that StartAsync method

Comment: There is an example from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having written a few hosted service processes within Service Fabric services, my approach tends to be as follows, using a timer that is started in StartAsync and stopped in StopAsync.

```
public class DisposableHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private bool _disposed;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(RunSmokeTests, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
    }
}
```